# Fail to Call R in the MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

I followed this post http://neurochannels.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-run-r-code-in-matlab.html, to install R(D)Com server in order to call R from the MATLAB, but i get error messages:

```
Error using openR (line 68)
Cannot connect to R.
Error using COM.StatConnectorSrv_StatConnector/Init
Error: Object returned error code: 0x80040013
```

What is going here? Are there any other ways to call R in MATLAB? I was told that

```
system
```

can bee used to call other execution programmes, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using R(D)COM and Matlab R-link for a while, I do not recommend it. The COM interface has trouble parsing many commands and it is difficult to debug the code. I recommend using a system command from Matlab as described in the [R Wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:callingr:matlab). This also avoids having to install RAndFriends.